# Recommendations, display fields from list in fluid free form

Tags: infopath, list-view, column, microsoft-access, datatable

I have a table to store a question/answer checklist. There are thirty five questions, each with a "Yes/No" and then a "Please Elaborate" for each field for when the answer is no that is a multiline rich text field. I did them as their own columns in the report with each row representing a new checklist.

I'd like to create a report or view for my user for my user which only displays the checklists that have at least one "no" among the 35 questions. I'd also like to arrange the results in a flexible way such that only the results for "no's" are displayed within each report.

Sure I could have a rule that hides a fields unless that have a "no" in them, the problem is, in a grid layout like the ones Sharepoint and Infopath seem to prefer, if even one user answers "no" for a given question, that column would remain open which would be ugly and space inefficient.

Take the below.

### ))))| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |

### R1| Yes| Yes| No |

### R2| Yes| No | Yes|

### R3| No | Yes| Yes|

In the above scenario, I can't collapse any of the columns because they all have no's. Given that I have 35 columns and want to display rich text results if needed, thats less than ideal.

The tools I have available are Access, Infopath and Sharepoint Designer. I have some comfort with each. I am not allowed to do back end coding.

Knowing all this, am I just doing this all wrong or is there a good way to approach this? Is there a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sharepoint Designer the "Preview Pane" style handles this well. It includes a column with a list of titles of list items and a preview pane for viewing individual items. It can be filtered to only show the reports that meet the criteria.